# React : How to delete multi selected check-boxes when a delete button is clicked in react

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, multi-select

I am new to react . Trying to delete all the checkboxes which are checked with a delete button which is on the top of the page . I am using functional component approach .

Please help me with this.

Comment: could you provide some code?
regards!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.